# Update if exists but using Primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to use following code for Update but facing an hudle how to get the ID from the select to use in an Update

any idea

My Code

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT ID
               FROM   table1
               WHERE  ptid = 1 
                      AND ssfid = 5) 
      UPDATE table1 WITH (updlock) 
      SET    ssfid = 5 
      WHERE  ptid = 1; - trying to use ID frm the above Table - how could i?
else
      insert goes here
```

Comment: Your query logic does not make sense to me.  The query in the exists clause already finds records where `ptid = 1` and `ssfid = 5`.  Then, what is the point of setting `ssfid = 5` in the update?

Comment: Agree with Tim here, I think you need to give us a more appropriate example. Perhaps you are updating `table2`? If not, then why do you need an `EXISTS` check in the first place? Just execute the `UPDATE`. It will either update one row or zero rows.

Comment: but else has an insert too

Comment: Consider `MERGE`.

Comment: noi idea how merge will fix that issue

Comment: @Seb, `MERGE` allows you to insert or update based on a join condition, in this case `ptid = 1 AND ssfid = 5`. You can insert `WHEN NOT MATCHED` and update `WHEN MATCHED`.

Comment: an simple test case using the above query will be nice to understand what i am trying to understand

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an updatable CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID, ssfid
    FROM table1
    WHERE ptid = 1 AND ssfid = 5
)

UPDATE cte
SET ssfid = 5;
```

The update logic does not make much sense, but this might be one way to execute what you described in your question.